# Wpf trigger in datagrid and background color

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

Thank you already found the answer, just use InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey

Comment: You already found the answer to what? I don't see any question.

Comment: I edited the post. The question was how to do that by selecting a row in a datagrid control, the other control of the same type and in the same form (another datagrid) did not lose the background color. It was a logical mistake on my part because if this does not happen, it is enough to simply state:
   <Style.Resources>
                         <SolidColorBrush x: Key = "{x: Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color = "Transparent" />
                     </Style.Resources>

Summary: There is no need to trigger to do what I wanted.